# How to set gradle path after installing using sdkman

Tags: java, hadoop, gradle, ubuntu-14.04, hipi

In Ubuntu 14.04 i have installed gradle using sdkman. When I execute "which gradle" in terminal from my primary account it shows path of gradle. Now I have another account hadoop having hduser, so after switching to hduser it is showing gradle is not installed. What should I do? How can I set path of gradle for hduser?

Comment: Don't know how sdkman installs it but normally you would just add it to the PATH environment variable for the other user.

Comment: The answer by @marvi is correct, just in case someone forget to specify the default version, sdkman wont always make the installed version the default one for Gradle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

sdkman installs software only for your current user (placed under `$HOME/.sdkman`). When you login as another user you will not have access to them. sdkman has init scripts called from your .bashrc/.zshrc that will append to your PATH. On my account gradle is `/Users/marvi/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/current/bin/gradle`.

For a multi user install I would do a manual install. First option here: http://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/09/06/install-gradle-ubuntu-16-04/

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to use command:

```
whereis gradle
```

Comment: For me that command dose not return anything. It's just blank.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was simply setting the default version of Gradle to 7.6 with `sdk use gradle 7.6` and reloading my ZSH config with `source ~/.zshrc`.
It seems like SDKMAN doesn't set a Gradle by default, you must do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative would be install SDKMan as a shared component

```
export SDKMAN_DIR="/usr/local/sdkman" && curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

Then install shared SDK component, i.e. gradle

```
sdk install gradle 4.10.2
```

Then for each user you want access to this 'shared' SDKs, just edit `.bashrc` or `.profile` file on the home path of those user and append these lines

```
export SDKMAN_DIR="/usr/local/sdkman"
[[ -s "/usr/local/sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "/usr/local/sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

They should have instant access to shared gradle after next login, test it with `gradle -v`

Comment: After installing it the way you suggested I receive the error 

`tee: /usr/local/sdkman/var/broadcast_id: Permission denied
tee: /usr/local/sdkman/var/broadcast: Permission denied`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, I just moved into the candidates directory and used chmod.

```
(xenial)lerie@localhost:~/.sdkman/candidates$ sudo chmod u+x -R .
(xenial)lerie@localhost:~/.sdkman/candidates$ gradle

Welcome to Gradle 7.0!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - File system watching enabled by default
 - Support for running with and building Java 16 projects
 - Native support for Apple Silicon processors
 - Dependency catalog feature preview

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Starting Daemon
```